# Chrome not persisting CORS cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, backbone.js, cross-domain

The setup uses a Backbone Model, Nginx server. The users enter their username and password which is then passed via a post. The server authenticates and returns a session cookie.

When the backend and front-end are on the same server (e.g. connect via localhost) the cookie is stored. However when the connection is remote, it is not stored in Chrome; however, it is stored in Safari and FireFox.

Ajax is setup via

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

The request headers are

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8102
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 59
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9102
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:9102/somefolder
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The response headers are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:9102
access-control-allow-credentials: true
vary: origin,accept-encoding
access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: na-auth-token=encrypted-string; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Thu, 27 Apr 2017 13:32:44 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 13:32:44 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

In FireFox and Safari the cookie is stored just fine, but in Chrome it gets the response and tosses the cookie without any notification.

## Update

The cookie is actually being saved under the localhost domain, however when you navigate back to the page (e.g. via a `window.location.reload`) the cookie disappears.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question lied in a library we were using

hapi-auth-cookie

The package updated and a flag was introduced `isSameSite`. Changed this value to false to allow the cors cookie to persist between pages loads.